# Generate union types from a list of types at runtime

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, pydantic

I want to do something like:

```py
from typing import List, Type
from pydantic import BaseModel

models: List[Type["BaseModel"]] = []


class ModelA(BaseModel):
    some_field: int


class ModelB(BaseModel):
    some_field: int


models.append(ModelA)
models.append(ModelB)


class ToShowInSwagger(BaseModel):
    types: List[[t for t in models]]  # <-----------------------------------------------------
    # or
    # types: List[*models]
```

In other words, I want to declare a list of possible types that a class field can be. How can it be done?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain more clearly / in more detail what it is you're trying to do, and why?

Comment: I think he wants a pydantic model which could return lots of types, and wants to avoid typing out all those types.  So it's not really *dynamic*, in that the models don't change at runtime, it's just not *explicit*.  In which case the question is 'can I generate a type from the union of the types of all these objects'

Comment: I'm working with fastapi framework. I want to automatically generate swagger by some list of pydantic models

Comment: @ForceQuell if that's what you mean the question could certainly be clearer.  do clarify if you really mean *dynamic* (changing at runtime) or *computed* (evaluated once when the program loads)

Comment: It sounds like you want some kind of registry system, in which you explicitly register `BaseModel` subclasses that are recognized by some other part of your system.

Comment: Why not just `List[Type["BaseModel"]]`?

Comment: @kaya3, cause these models have different structure

Comment: Then how about writing your own subclass of `BaseModel` which all your models inherit from, and using that?

Comment: @2e0byo, yeah, it's not dynamically

Comment: @kaya3, I want fastapi swagger to show all possible variants. if I create a subclass and give it to swagger, it will only show one model

Comment: I don't know if this is possible (generating union types from a list of types at runtime), but regardless, the question should be updated to make it clear that that's what you're trying to do.

I don't know if it's a good idea either, as it seems to make some of the declarative logic of fastapi/pydantic a bit less declarative.  But I can see why one would want to do it and I'll think about it.

Answer (score 0):

I might create some intermediary base class for all models that you want to be able to show in `ToShowInSwagger`.  Here I called it `VisibleModel`:

```py
from typing import List, Type
from pydantic import BaseModel


class VisibleModel(BaseModel):
    pass


class ModelA(VisibleModel):
    some_field: int


class ModelB(VisibleModel):
    some_field: int


class ToShowInSwagger(BaseModel):
    types: List[Type[VisibleModel]] = sorted(VisibleModel.__subclasses__(),
                                             key=lambda cls: cls.__name__)
```

This way `types` will only be those models that are explicitly subclasses of `VisibleModel`.

The downside to this is this fixes `ToShowInSwagger.types` to only those `VisibleModel` subclasses that were actually defined by the time `ToShowInSwagger` is defined.  To make this more dynamic you might need to make `ToShowInSwagger.types` a classproperty or something like that.